# exchange parameters between apache cxf interceptor and jaxrs client

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I'm creating an Apache CXF JAX-RS client and adding an inInterceptor

```
MyProxy proxy = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://path.to.url", MyProxy.class);
ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(service);

config.getInInterceptors().add(new RemoveAlertsInterceptor());
```

How can I set a parameter inside the `RemoveAlertsInterceptor`, which I can read from the proxy?